# What is the colorized version of the Linux "top" program?

Tags: linux, command-line, top

[image]

I didn't know "top" had a nicer colorized version like this. What is the command? Does anyone recognize this?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

#### [htop](http://hisham.hm/htop/)

> This is htop, an interactive process viewer for Linux. It is a text-mode application (for console or X terminals) and requires ncurses.

[image]

Comment: The screenshot from OP does show htop, however top *also* support colors, process tree and bars like htop. it's just not the default.

Answer (score 17):

Try z/Z in top

Comment: What ZZ top? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZZ_Top

Comment: "she's got colours, she knows how to use them" :-)

Comment: Also, 'W' writes a toprc (Normally to: `~/.config/procps/toprc`) (it will save color settings as well after hitting 'z', or any new mappings).

Answer (score 3):

The programm in the screenshot is `htop`.

But you even can colorize the powerful `top` program. That for type in `top` capital `Z` and follow the instructions printed there.

Afterwards save to the configuration file typing capital `W` and confirm with `y`.